# Still getting this error: Cannot access class com.sun.javafx.print.Units (in module javafx.graphics)

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-11

I have been trying to create a custom paper for an 80mm thermal printer. I did research and came up with this:

```
Paper myPaper = PrintHelper.createPaper("Roll80", 80, 310, Units.MM);
```

However, after getting this error I tried all available options on stack overflow and some other githubs pages but to no avail. I tried adding this `--add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.print=ALL-UNNAMED` to my VM Options but I still get the same error. I am using a modular project and below is my module-info.java class:

```
module my.enterp {
  requires javafx.base;
  requires javafx.fxml;
  requires javafx.graphics;
  requires javafx.controls;
  requires javafx.web;
  opens sample;
}
```

I have been stuck on this error for some days now.

Comment: you need to klick the green check mark to accept the answer, you can do that with reputation 1

Answer (score 3):

Since the code is in the `my.enterp` module, you need to export the package to it, not to the unnamed module (`ALL-UNNAMED`):

```
--add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.print=my.enterp
```

Make sure to export it both at compile-time and runtime.

Comment: How do I export it both at compile-time and runtime?

Comment: @SampsonAli You need to add the above both to the compiler options (`javac`) and VM/runtime options (`java`). Instructions vary by IDE.